# Timeline buttons are yielding errors across the network

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, timeline

Clicking on the timeline button for any post at the moment will yield the infamous "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error.

[image]

This has gone from being Meta.SE-specific to being network-wide.

Running Windows 10, Chrome version 81.0.4044.113 (64 bit)

Comment: (Extra: The mod-show timeline option is giving the same error)

Comment: working on fix now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue has been fixed. Timelines are back.

Comment: What was the cause of this error?

Comment: @RobertColumbia [Something like this](https://xkcd.com/1739/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix!